# Network admin "Sites" page - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I'm running a Wordpress multisite network, to manage the sites on the network I go to the "sites"page which displays the following headings:

URL  -  Last Updated  -  Registered  -  Users

To make this more useful I'd like to add the name of the site to this table. I have now added a column through using this code:

```
add_filter('wpmu_blogs_columns', 'add_site_name_column');
function add_site_name_column($site_columns) {
    $site_columns['site_name'] = 'Site Name';
    return $site_columns;
}
```

However I cant now work out how to put the site name into the column?

Comment: The answer is "yes, it's possible".  What have you tried? What code have you implemented?

Comment: I've read the following article - https://pippinsplugins.com/add-user-id-column-to-the-wordpress-users-table/ but am struggling to understand which part of this tells wordrpess which page and table to add the column to.

Answer (score 1):

Check in the file `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-ms-site-list-table.php`, specifically look for the `get_columns` method.

The key to doing this will be for you to add a filter that works with the columns:

```
add_filter( 'wpmu_blogs_columns', 'my_custom_blog_columns' );

function my_custom_blog_columns( $sites_columns ) {
    // Modify $site_columns here....
    return $site_columns;
}
```

Typically you would add this filter in your theme's `functions.php` file, or in the plugin file(s) you are developing.

Comment: Thanks, that's great, I'll give that a shot now